# Changing toolset and VS version does not change MSC_VER of my objects

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors

I am attempting to compile a project after migrating it from VS2010 to VS2012 and I receive the following build errors:

> 1. msvcprt.lib(newaop_s.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1600' in
>      jwh_arx_circle.obj
> 2. rxapi.lib(libinit.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1600' in
>      jwh_arx_circle.obj

The **jwh_...** files are my objects and I have the toolset set to **v110** in **VS2012** and my objects are still showing up with `MSC_VER 1600` instead of 
`1700`
. If I switch to VS2013 and use the v120 tookit, the `MSC_VER` of the microsoft object changes to `1800` but my objects are all still `1600`.

I have cleaned and rebuilt and ensured that the files are being deleted and recreated.

I have VS 2008, 2012, 2013, and 2015 installed on my machine.  I installed 2008 then 2013, 2015 and finally 2012.  I'm concerned this might have something to do with it, my boss instructs us all to install VS in order but I just had to install 2012 for a recent job, otherwise I wouldn't use it here.

Comment: If you are still getting that error, then you are not building that obj or you are not building that obj with the toolset you think you are.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I had manually included VS directories from older versions.  Once I removed these the MSC_VER lined up.